# GAMM fit much worse after autocorrelation is taken into account

Tags: r, time-series, mgcv, autocorrelation

I am looking at the effects of drought events on soil gas fluxes timeseries using `R` and `gam` and `gamm` from the `mgcv` package since the data is seasonally variable. The data is also missing winter months, so, k = the number of months measured or k = number of years measured. I have also included a factor variable 'moisture_status' identifying whether the gas flux was in a 'soil drought' period or a 'soil non-drought period'. Removing the moisture_status variable does not resolve the issue described below.

model structure:
`gam(CO2_flux ~ moisture_status + s(month, bs = "cc", k = 8) + s(time, bs="cr", k = 9), data = df)`

This model has a great fit (R-sq.(adj) = 0.833, Deviance explained = 83.40%) but shows autocorrelation in the ACF plot (though very little in the PACF plot). Below on the left are the four `gam.check()` models, on the right are `plot(model)` with and without residuals, then `acf()` and `pacf()`.
[image]

So, I controlled for autocorrelation using `correlation = corAR1(form = ~1|year, p = 1)` and compare the AIC of models with `p =` ranging from 1:5. Model structure:

`gamm(CO2_flux ~ moisture_status + s(month, bs = "cc", k = 8) + s(time, bs="cr", k = 9), correlation = corAR1(form = ~1|year, p = 1), method="REML", data = df)`

The `gamm` models that control for autocorrelation have an abysmal fit, regardless of the value for `p =`. According to the AICs, the `gamm` with `p = 5` was the best but has an R-sq.(adj) = -0.0746 and very poor residual structure. Below on the left are again the four `gam.check()` models, and on the right `plot(model$gam)` with and without residuals, then `acf(residuals(model$lme, type = "normalized")` and `pacf(residuals(model$lme, type = "normalized")`.
[image]

I have looked at every post, blog, scientific article, and book I could find on gam(m)s and autocorrelation, but no examples presented seem to have the same issue. Can anyone give me some insight as to the cause and potential solution to this? Here is some [sample data](https://b2drop.eudat.eu/s/aXEARqt3esG4YRN).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems better when you group by month, perhaps because a year is too long.

```
CO2_flux_example <- read.csv()
df = CO2_flux_example
library(mgcv)
m=gam(CO2_flux~ s(month, k=8) + s(time, k=3), data = df)
summary(m)
gam.check(m)
plot(m)
m1=gamm(CO2_flux~ s(month, k=8) + s(time, k=3), data = df, correlation=corARMA(form=~1|month, p=1))
m2=gamm(CO2_flux~ s(month, k=8) + s(time, k=3), data = df, correlation=corARMA(form=~1|month, p=2))
m3=gamm(CO2_flux~ s(month, k=8) + s(time, k=3), data = df, correlation=corARMA(form=~1|month, p=3))
m4=gamm(CO2_flux~ s(month, k=8) + s(time, k=3), data = df, correlation=corARMA(form=~1|month, p=4))
m5=gamm(CO2_flux~ s(month, k=8) + s(time, k=3), data = df, correlation=corARMA(form=~1|month, p=5))
summary(m1$gam)
summary(m2$gam)
summary(m3$gam)
summary(m4$gam)
summary(m5$gam)
plot(m1$gam)
plot(m2$gam)
plot(m3$gam)
plot(m4$gam)
plot(m5$gam)
anova(m1$lme, m2$lme, m3$lme, m4$lme, m5$lme)
```

Output suggests that ARMA(p=2) model is best among p=1,2,3,4,5 with `R-sq.(adj) =  0.812`

```
       Model df      AIC      BIC    logLik   Test   L.Ratio p-value
m1$lme     1  7 7820.564 7860.364 -3903.282                         
m2$lme     2  8 7794.740 7840.226 -3889.370 1 vs 2 27.823941  <.0001
m3$lme     3  9 7792.965 7844.137 -3887.483 2 vs 3  3.774478  0.0520
m4$lme     4 10 7792.014 7848.871 -3886.007 3 vs 4  2.951090  0.0858
m5$lme     5 11 7792.861 7855.404 -3885.431 4 vs 5  1.152921  0.2829
```

[image]

The GAM residuals still show autocorrelation, of course, but the standardized residuals no longer do.

```
acf(residuals(m2$gam), main="GAM residuals")
acf(residuals(m2$lme, type="normalized"), main="Normalized residuals")
```

[image]

Comment: That did the trick. The fit after taking autocorrelation into account is now acceptable. Thank you very much for your help!